# Vim - Add in visual block selection

Tags: vim

there is something I often try to do in Vim and either I'm not using the right method or it is not possible without a plugin:

**Appending text to several lines at the same time in visual block selection.**

For exemple:

```
[1] 
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]

// I want to select all the numbers in a visual block, press 'a' then append 0
// And get this ->

[10]
[20]
[30]
[40]
[50]
[60]
```

To get around this issue right now I would go to the closest identical char I can find, press `'s'` and then append the deleted char + the char I want to add. Or use a macro.

If you know how to do this properly or if you can link me to a plugin that allows 
 `[ visual block -> 'a' ]` let me know!

Comment: `:%s/\d\zs/0/g` can also do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there, it's `A`, not `a`.

You can also use `I` to prepend, see `:help blockwise-operators`.

Comment: Fun thing is that I figured it out for `I` to comment several lignes at a time before using a plugin for it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the block and then use:

```
:norm a0
```